# arcpy Add Join with "KEEP_ALL" Does not Keep All

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, attribute-joins, arcgis-10.5

Using arcpy for ArcGIS 10.5.1, I'm joining a feature layer to a table using `arcpy.AddJoin_management()` with the `KEEP_ALL` option in order to keep all features whether they have a related record in the joined table or not.  However, after running the join, the only features in the layer are those that have a related record in the joined table.

My code is:

```
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(inFeatures, tmpLayer)
    arcpy.MakeTableView_management(joinTable, tmpView, "Classification = '{}'".format(seasonClassification))
    arcpy.AddJoin_management(tmpLayer, inField, tmpView, joinField, join_type="KEEP_ALL")
```

I know I've had this working as expected in other scripts, but not in this case.

What am I doing wrong?  How do I get it to keep all features after the join?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that it works as expected when joining to a table, but not when joining to a table view (or at least, not a table view with a definition query - I haven't tested without the query).

So my work around is to use `arcpy.TableToTable_conversion()` to create a temporary in_memory table from the table view, and join to that instead of joining to the table view itself.

This code is now working fine for me:

```
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(inFeatures, tmpLayer)
arcpy.MakeTableView_management(joinTable, tmpView, "Classification = '{}'".format(seasonClassification))
#  Need to use a temporary table for the join, otherwise "KEEP_ALL" fails to keep all when joining to a view (at least in this case)
arcpy.TableToTable_conversion(tmpView, os.path.dirname(tmpTable), os.path.basename(tmpTable))
arcpy.Delete_management(tmpView)
arcpy.AddJoin_management(tmpLayer, inField, tmpTable, joinField, join_type="KEEP_ALL")
```

I'm not sure if this is a known limitation, or a bug.  I've been unable to find any documentation for this behaviour.

Comment: This is another example of 'things I hate about ArcGIS".  Functions that "should work" and very often "do work" on another computer/dataset/day/etc... refuse to work as expected and then you're forced to come up a funky workaround.

Comment: Yup.  If I had a dollar for every time I had to come up with a work around for weird ArcGIS behaviour...